Password reset email link leads to access denied
When users on my site request a password reset link and click the link they are taken to an access denied page when they click on the link.
Clicking on the link in the email will direct users to https://mysite.com/user/reset/[uid].
Right clicking on the link and selecting copy link address will give them the correct link, https://mysite.com/user/reset/[uid]/[timestamp]/[hashvalue].
When I inspect the email on gmail I can see the href value is correct so I'm not sure why this is happening.
On outlook the email href is completely wrong, but the title attribute is somewhat correct.

I stumbled onto this post: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3401709
Once I changed the cookie_samesite values on my services.yml the links started working.
parameters:
  session.storage.options:
    cookie_samesite: Lax

For both gmail and outlook the links still end up taking users to https://mysite.com/user/reset/[uid]
but for some reason they no longer get the access denied error message.

You had strict?
